# Is it possible to generically access the response object in a Django Rest Framework ModelViewSet?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add cache-control headers to a Django Rest Framework ModelViewSet.

The only way I can figure out how to do it is to individually override each ViewSet action (view, retrieve, create etc) and append the header to that action's response, as below.

Is there a better way to do it? Can I access all the responses more generically, so I don't have to override every single action?

Thanks

John

```
class EntityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Company.objects.all().order_by('name')

    # add cache-contol the hard way
    def list(self, request):
        response = super(EntityViewSet, self).list(request)
        response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
        return response

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        response = super(EntityViewSet, self).retrieve(request, pk=None)
        response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
        return response

    def create(self, request):
        response = super(EntityViewSet, self).create(request, data=request.data)
        response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
        return response

    router.register(r'entities', EntityViewSet)
```

Comment: I have not used rest framework that much but looking into its documentation the design is basically django class based views. I think you can create a subclass of ModelViewSet overriding `dispatch` method which is usually called for response and returns a `response` object and add your response to that.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I was after. I'll try it out and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that seems to work very nicely, thanks. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As per sagarchalise's suggestion that I simply override Django's dispatch method, this works:

```
class UnCachedModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(UnCachedModelViewSet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
        return response

class EntityViewSet(UnCachedModelViewSet):
    queryset = Company.objects.all().order_by('name')
    //no need to override each action now
```